# Measurability of orbits by continuous actions

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, group-actions, measurable-sets

Let $G$ a topological group, $(X,\mathcal{B})$ a measurable space, and $G \curvearrowright X$ a measurable action, that is, the map $G \times B \rightarrow B$ is measurable, when $G \times X$ is endowed with the product $\sigma$-algebra of the Borel sets on $G$ and $\mathcal{B}$.

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $G$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$.

- Is it true that $KB  \in \mathcal{B}$?
- Can you provide sufficient topological conditions on $G$, or conditions on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$, such that the statement is true?

*Thoughts:* When trying to produce counterexamples, like in the following attempt, the assumption of measurability of the action looks difficult to prove or disprove.

*Attempt 1:* If $G=X=\mathbb{R}$, if $G$ is endowed with the usual topology, if $G$ acts on $X$ by translations, if $\mathcal{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ that are either countable or of countable complement, $B := \{0\}$ and $K := [0,1]$, then $KB \not \in \mathcal{B}$. However, I don't think the action is measurable: if $a \in X$, $\{(g,x) \ \vert \ g\cdot x = a\} = \{(x,y) \ \vert \ x+y = a\}$ and I don't believe that a line of slope $-1$ can be in the product $\sigma$-algebra.

*Attempt 2:* If $X$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and if both $K$ and $B$ are compact, then $KB$ is a Borel set. We can form the set $\{A \in \mathcal{B} \ \vert \ KB \in \mathcal{B}\}$ and we know that it contains all the compacts subsets of $X$. It is closed under taking countable unions, but probably not under taking complements.

Comment: There are $K,B\subseteq\Bbb R$ with $K$ compact, $B$ Borel and $K+B$ not Borel, so this fails even for the translation action $\Bbb R\curvearrowright\Bbb R$. I will dig up a reference and write a proper answer later.

Comment: If it is true, it is the best answer I could expect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erdös and Stone proved that there are $K,B\subseteq\Bbb R$ where $K$ is compact and $B$ is $G_\delta$ such that $K+B$ is not Borel in the following paper. The paper uses an explicit construction due to Von Neumann to produce a perfect $P\subseteq\Bbb R$ that is linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, but the existence of such a set is an immediate consequence of Mycielski's theorem (see for example Theorem 19.1 and Exercise 19.2i in Kechris *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*).

> Erdös, P., and A. H. Stone. “On the Sum of Two Borel Sets.” Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, vol. 25, no. 2, American Mathematical Society, 1970, pp. 304–06, https://doi.org/10.2307/2037209.

This shows that even for the (continuous) translation action of $\Bbb R$ on itself the property you are interested in fails (and the argument in Erdös-Stone generalizes to many topological groups). A simpler construction is given in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2785650/136041) answer.

Comment: Thank you for this very useful answer.

Comment: @plop while thinking about your question I started wondering what’s the smallest $\sigma$-algebra we can put on the reals that fixes this example. Being unable to work it out myself I asked on MO, you might be interested too https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408912/what-is-the-smallest-sigma-algebra-of-reals-that-is-closed-under-addition-of